# Is there an Excel formula that will search a cell for certain test and return the letters searched and 11 numbers to its right?

Tags: excel-formula

Is the following possible and if so what formula would I use to pull this off?

- Column A has rows of Summary data from problem tickets which will contain the problem ticket ID and other text.
- The problem ID will always be 15 characters in length
- The format of the Problem ID is USPM followed by the number for example USPM12345678911

Is there a formula that will look at for example cell A2 for `*USPM*` and return everything within the `* *` IN CELL b2? For example A2= (hehegdyyff USPM12345678911 ididuufffuf) the formula looks at A2 to see if it contains USPM and if it does it returns USPM and the next 11 characters to its right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You use the `FIND()` and `MID()` commands. Something like this:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("USPM",A2),15)
```

Check out the help pages for both functions for additional details.

In case `USPM` is not present in your input, you may want to use a condition to avoid the error:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("USPM",A2)),"",MID(A2,FIND("USPM",A2),15))
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The `FIND()` command searches for a word in a case sensitive manner. If you may have lowercase characters in your `"USPM"` marker, you may want to use `SEARCH()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Alexis Wilke I tried using: =MID(A2,FIND('USPM',A2),19) and got an error.

Comment: @Damon.Martin Sorry, you probably need to use double quotes. My mistake. Also this first formula does not take in account the possibility that `A2` does not include `"USPM"` and if it doesn't you also get an error (because `FIND()` returns an error in that case and `MID()` is not going to be happy about it.) So I added another example with an `IF()` which returns an empty string when `FIND()` fails. Also, I changed the length to 15 so it works with your example.